# Printing a Div with some prefilled data and then printing a hidden div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

I apologize in advance if this question appears vague.
I am porting an older Silverlight Application into a html/web api application.

The application allows various vendors to apply for licenses to business with a sovereign tribe and then allows them the opportunity to print a license once it is issues to them.

The license looks something like this

[image: License Image]

Almost 100% of the text in the License comes from the database.

One idea I have is to create an html table and set the background for the table as the certificate image, then use cells to position the text from the server.

However I have hit a wall for a couple of reasons, 
1)license needs to print full page and only the license not the rest of the site, like the print button.
2) Before the license prints, I need to print a cover letter that is inside a hidden div.

So ideally, user clicks a button and out prints a cover letter followed by the license properly formatted.

Any pointers or suggestions are very welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css @media to apply styles only when printing the document and not when just viewing:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.cover {
  /* hidden cover */
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
/* fills entire sheet of paper */

.cert {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
/* only apply when printing */

@media print {
  /* show cover in print */
  .cover {
    display: block;
  }
  /* hide other elements in print */
  button {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="window.print()">print</button>
<div class="cover">COVERLETTER</div>
<div class="cert">CERTIFICATE</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I hope this helps others in my shoes as well. Would you have any opinion on if I should use tables to position the text on top of the div or is there a better way of doing this ?